# Static keyword saves value returned by function?

Tags: c++, static, constants

I have several functions in a program I'm writing that use a value I need to calculate with a very slow function.  This value will change every time the program is rerun, so I can't just store a static value.  Below is an example.

```
void this_gets_called_frequently()
{
    static int value = slow_function();

    //do stuff with the above value
}
```

My main problem here is not one of the program not working, rather of neatness.  I don't really want to initialise a global variable and store the value in that, since it is not going to change once calculated.  Would using the static keyword in the manner shown above only call the function above to be calculated once?  Would a const keyword added in there help?

Thanks everyone, this was answered perfectly!

Comment: You have it exactly right - a static local variable will be initialized only once, the first time that piece of code is executed.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Unless `slow_function()` throws an exception ;)

Comment: Yes, unless you are in C++03 and call `this_gets_called_frequently` from multiple threads. IIRC C++11 silently guarantees that `value` is initialized only once by only one thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an initialization of local `static` variable will happen at most once (although I recall some compiler versions could have problems with multithreading here).
`const` is not required, in this case it's mostly a matter of readability and taste.

Answer (score 0):

> Would using the static keyword in the manner shown above only call the function above to be calculated once?

Yes, on the first invocation of `this_gets_called_frequently`

> Would a const keyword added in there help?

No. But add `const` for documentation value.

Answer (score 0):

Use may use the thread local variables from C++11, if they are available in your compiler. If you are on Windows, you can use similar `TlsAlloc` API. It is there since the dawn of Win32.

Comment: That would still require calling `slow_function` per each thread.